# How to TextField hide/show click on the text in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an Alert dialog in which have three option, I want to that when I click on the `text(Enter RC Number)` once the below `TextField` will be shown and again click on `text(Enter RC Number)` second-time the below `TextField` hide and (the below `TextField` will be hidden by default) how to do this please suggest to me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
void main()=> runApp(MyHomePages());

class MyHomePages  extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "KYC Formm",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePageDesign(title: "Kyc form"),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePageDesign extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePageDesign({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePageDesign> {
  var _isVisible = false ;
  TextEditingController phoneController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Choose any one'),
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text("Capture Photo",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text("Pick Photo",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      setState(() {
//                        _isVisible = !_isVisible;
//                        if(_isVisible){
//                          _isVisible=true;
//                        }else{
//                          _isVisible=false;
//                        }
                      });

                    },
                    child: Text("Enter RC Number",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                Visibility(
                  visible: _isVisible,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 200.0,
                      height: 60.0,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Enter RC No',
                        ),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: new FlatButton(
                    child: new Text('OK',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.teal
                      ),),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],

            ),
          );
          // );
        });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child:Container(
          width: 160.0,
          height: 50.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 5.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text('Open Dialog'),
            onPressed: () {
              _displayDialog(context);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the changes should place in the dialog, you need to use a `StatefullBuilder`. Also, you need to call `setState()` when changing the visibility in the dialog so that the changes apply to it.

```
  _toggleVisibility() { // this is new
    setState(() {
      _isVisible = !_isVisible;
    });
  }

  _unsetVisibility() { // this is new, used when closing the dialog
    setState(() {
      _isVisible = false;
    });
  }

  _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) { // this is new
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Choose any one'),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      "Capture Photo",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      "Pick Photo",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        _toggleVisibility(); // this is new
                        setState(() {}); // this is new
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Enter RC Number",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: _isVisible,
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 200.0,
                        height: 60.0,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 10.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 0.0),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Enter RC No',
                          ),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: new FlatButton(
                      child: new Text(
                        'OK',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _unsetVisibility(); // this is new
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
        });
  }
```

Comment: Actually I want TextField, show, and hide click on the text.. show the Textfield when I press text once, and when I press the text again the  TextField hide. how to do this.

Comment: I've edited my answer to match what you want, check it out. @NeeluModanwal

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 2.0**

Your code seems fine, the problem was **AlertDialog doesn't rebuild, even if the value is changing**. So in order to see the changes, **the solution is [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html)** which has to be there to wrap your `AlertDialog`, it will help your Widget to rebuild

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog();
      }
    );
)
```

Now, let us jump into the code. *I have used your code only with some error rectifications, so you can simply copy-paste the code, and see the result*

**Please Note:** I have demonstrated your `_displayDialog()`, since it had the issue. So just use this in your code, and rest your code will do

```
void _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        // this was required, rest is same
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, setState){
            return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Choose any one'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text("Capture Photo",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text("Pick Photo",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() => _isVisible = !_isVisible);
                  },
                  child: Text("Enter RC Number",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
              Visibility(
                visible: _isVisible,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 60.0,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 0.0,bottom: 10.0,right: 0.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Enter RC No',
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text('OK',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.teal
                    ),),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              )
            ]
          )
        );
          }
        );
      });
  }
```

**RESULT**

[image: Result GIF]

Comment: Thanks, Sir for reply Actually, Sir, your code is working but when I  implement it in my project it is not working  I don't understand what is a mistake here in my code. I want that you implement this code in my code which  I have shared with you.

Comment: Okay, let me take a look at that @NeeluModanwal, and we will figure something out to get the end result. Just wait for some time, I will update you with the working code then :)